# Create storyboard screen with two inherit classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, tableview, viewcontroller

I'm new in iOS programming and I have a problem with connect in one screen two separate screen models. I have an table view and typical view controller. When I want control elements of this screen, I need two separate class, where one inherit from UITableView and second from UIViewController, because in Objective-C I cannot create class, which inherit from two other classes. How can I control class of table view from view controller class. I must say, that simple composition isn't solve my problem, because I don't know how to connect dynamically class with a screen's model.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

And set for your UITableView .delegate and .datasource or link it in story board

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, but this answer must be completed, because in code of view controller must be added few functions:

```js
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [regions count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region.timeZoneWrappers count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region name];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]];
    }
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    TimeZoneWrapper *timeZoneWrapper = [region.timeZoneWrappers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timeZoneWrapper.localeName;
    return cell;
}
```